# Asp.Net MVC Assembly Reference Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I add the reference system.web.routing dll and I add namespace in all page and also add in web.config page, but here the error in add query string parameter line. Can someone findthe error and tell the answer?

```
 var isDescending = string.CompareOrdinal(Model.SortBy, ViewData["ColumnName"].ToString()) == 0 && Model.SortAscending;
    var routeData = new RouteValueDictionary { { "sortBy", ViewData["ColumnName"].ToString() }, { "ascending", !isDescending } };

// Add in the querystring parameters *except* for the paging ones (as sorting should send us back to the first page of data)
routeData.AddQueryStringParameters().ExceptFor("page", "pageSize");

var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
if (string.CompareOrdinal(Model.SortBy, ViewData["ColumnName"].ToString()) == 0)
{
    if (Model.SortAscending)
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("class", "sortAsc");
    }
    else
    { 
        htmlAttributes.Add("class", "sortDesc");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have added system.web.routing dll and you have added namespace in all page and also add in web.config page you said that fine

so you have to remove this line and run the program surely u will get output

```
 routeData.AddQueryStringParameters().ExceptFor("page", "pageSize");
```